# DotNetNuke Popups for login and registration not working

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

Have 3 sites on same DotNetNuke installation, but for the oldest site the popups don't work on registration and login pages. Instead, the forms are presented in a separated page as if the popup option was not set on site settings.

Already tried many things, some desperate, as:

- Use custom pages
- Enable skin widgets
- Check event log, no errors
- Even change skin and container. Gravity Skin has one special skin for popus but that also didn't work

Documentation doesn't point to any dependency, so i'm blind here.

Comment: Please tell us which version is the oldest site? That's probably the issue!

Comment: They are all on the same DotNetNuke Installation, version 7.03.02. Note that site, in DotNetNuke terms is not a IIS site.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you tried the "Enable-Popups" checkbox. You can find it in Site settings -> Advanced Settings -> Usability Settings.